# ng-pattern allow only letters, numbers, dot, underscore and dash

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

How'd allow for an input using `ng-pattern` only: `letters`, `numbers`, `dot`, `underscore` and `dash`  `( . _ -)`?

Already tried the following ones

UPDATE:

```
$scope.validationPattern = '/^[a-zA-Z\d\-\_]+$/';

<input ng-model="model" type="text" ng-pattern="{{validationPattern}}" />
```

Comment: And you tried... what pattern and code are you using?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: see updated question.

Comment: Great, and what does not work? Note there is no dot in the pattern (after your edit). Try it like this `'/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$/'` and use `<input ng-model="model" type="text" ng-trim="false" ng-pattern="{{validationPattern}}" />` (add `ng-trim="false"`).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Judging by your requirements, you need to add a dot to the pattern:

```
$scope.regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$';
```

and add `ng-trim="false"` to the `<input>` tag so as to disallow leading/trailing spaces.

See [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/8QmXGz9kbF0NNQCHgk1i?p=preview)

Comment: one more question, if I'd like to add slash (`/`) too why `^[a-zA-Z0-9._-/]+$` does not works?

Comment: Ok, just follow either strategy: 1) escape the hyphen and do not care what you add at the end of the character class or 2) always keep the hyphen at the end of the  character class. If you escape in a string literal use double backslashes.

Comment: Thanks! in plunker it works but not in my project. I'm getting: `[$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [^] in expression [^[a-zA-Z0-9._/-]+$]` , any idea? this is how the input looks like: `<input ng-model="model" type="text" ng-blur="onChange(model)" ng-change="didEndChanges(model)" ng-class="{'invalid': !isFieldValid}" ng-pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9._/-]+$" ng-trim="false" data-i18n-attr="{placeholder: 'common.scanData' }" ng-disabled="disabled" placeholder="Scan data" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-pattern" style="">`

Comment: Try `ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9._\/-]+$/"`

Answer (score 4):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][A-Za-z0-9._-]*
```

this one works

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ._-]+$/
```

This regex seems appropriate enough for you if it don't directly fit in ng-pattern make necessary adjustments, like.

in controller add

`$scope.pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ._-]+$/;`

now in html use `ng-pattern="pattern"`

Tested using this : http://www.regextester.com/

Accepts numbers, alphabets and three symbols(.-_)